# CodeMirror styles are not working after decorating the textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, codemirror

I have a `Nuxtjs/Vuejs` application within which I have a `textarea` related to `XML/JSON`. After the user provides the values for these `textarea` they will be decorated with `XML/JSON` using `CodeMirror`.

Initially, the `textarea` will have the height of `78vh` and I would like my `CodeMirror` to have the same `height and width` after making the beautification and include the `horizontal/vertical scroll bar` to move if the content exceeds the border.

I tried to add the CSS property like this but it's not working at all and I get the huge scroll bar to my browser rather within `textarea`.

```
.CodeMirror{
    height: 78vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I also tried adding `!important` and `div > div > div > div > div.CodeMirror {` to ensure I am taking parent into consideration but nothing seems to work for me.

Can someone please let me know what I need to do so that my `textarea` will have same `height and width` and include a `horizontal and vertical scrollbar` within itself?

I have added my sample code in the [CodeSandBox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-water-g14zd?file=/pages/index.vue): https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-water-g14zd?file=/pages/index.vue

Answer (score 0):

I added in JS instead of in CSS and that worked for me:

```
for (const s of document.getElementsByClassName('CodeMirror')) {
        s.style.border = '1px solid black'
      }
```